Is this pattern for working with rate limits bug-free?
I am using a third party api, and I have a limit of api calls per minute, per 15 minutes and per hour. Usually, the per hour limit is less than the rate per minute times 60 (60 minutes in one hour).
And sometimes I want to do a batch update. So I want to call this endpoint multiple times, but also I don't want to go over the limit because I will get an error.
I'm using this for my worker services implemented in C#.
I made this snippet
int ratePerHour = HardCodedRatePerHour;
int counter = 0;
int rateLimitPerMinute = ratePerHour / 60
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
foreach (var item in itemsToBeUpdated) 
{
    await UpdateItemUsingThirdPartyWithRateLimit(item, stoppingToken)
    counter++;
    counter = await WaitInCaseOfGoingOverRateLimit(rateLimitPerMinute, stopwatch, counter, stoppingToken);
}

and the method WaitInCaseOfGoingOverRateLimit is as follows:
private static async Task<int> WaitInCaseOfGoingOverRateLimit(int ratePerMinute, Stopwatch stopwatch, int countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    int duration = (int)stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
    if (duration < 60 && countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart >= ratePerMinute)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sleeping for {60 - duration} seconds. In the last minute, {countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart} number of items have been updated");
        await Task.Delay((60 - duration) * 1000, stoppingToken);
        countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart = 0;
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }
    else if (duration > 60)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No need to sleep on this batch. In the last minute, {countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart} number of items have been updated");
        countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart = 0;
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }

    return countOfItemsProcessedSinceLastStopWatchRestart;
}

To explain the method:

I will restart the stopwatch if the duration exceeded 60 seconds or
the rate limit has exceeded.
I will always set the counter to 0 when I restart the stopwatch
If the rate limit is exceeded I will delay the rest of the execution
by how much time is left to start a new minute
If the rate limit is not exceeded nor the stopwatch hasn't passed 60 seconds from the last restart, I will keep the counter the same value as it is
The counter is increased by one in every for loop iteration

Is this one of the correct ways of handling rate limits? Are there any suggestions?

i'll just call the api, get the response. if it says over limit, then wait for some time, call again. it is because the way they calculate the limit may be different from what you showed at here. you never know.

s.a. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/http-ratelimiter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745258/how-to-retry-a-polly-rate-limit-when-the-rate-limit-has-exceeded - Polly policies are what we use.

@urlreader That's a really good solution. I've never thought the calculation of the limit can be different. I think Polly suggestion by Christoph would be a good tool to use for your solution. On another note, the third-party we use sends us alerts for using the APIs for more than we should have, and this worker service is running over night. So preferably, we want to limit the alerts by the third party to be alerts that correspond to actual rate limits we need to worry about; those used in production apps during the day

I'd use this: TimeSpan sleepDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0).Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed);. It's better to stay in TimeSpan than to use and int to represent milliseconds.

Also, your description say "exceeded 60", and it seems you're phrasing the first condition in the negative, so I wonder if it should be if (duration <= 60 && 

@ChristophLütjen, thanks for sharing! the first link is a great article and same as what I'm trying to do.

you are right @Enigmativity. it's possible that on the 60th second I go over the limit with the current implementation. I'll have to make the change.

@urlreader, has it ever happened to you that the calculation from the third-party is different from the number of times you send a request within a minute? And how different was it?

One common problem is the question when exactly does a window start? Imagine a scenario with 100 requests per second: You send 1 request, 30s later 99 request then you'll wait 30 seconds and send the next 100 requests. What if the remote side did the reset right before your 99 requests? Your 100 requests will fail and you'll have to wait 30 more seconds. You could track the exact timestamp of each request and then check how many request you've sent in the past minute. In most other cases, it might be hard to avoid error responses.

@ChristophLütjen, I think that won't be an issue. If the remote side reset right before my 99 request, then the 100th request is the first request for it.

Nope. If your 1 minute windows starts right before your first request you'll send 1+99 => 100. Then you'll wait until 60 seconds starting from your first request are over and send the next batch of 100. Now we assume the remote side started the window right before your 99 "batch". As a result, 99+100 would be in the same window on the remote side.

You are right! @ChristophLütjen. Great stuff! When there is an imbalance in the number of requests that happens in the same duration of time, this error will happen.

@ChristophLütjen, what do you think about this? I created a list called logs, and when I want to check whether to wait or not, I'll check how many requests has happened 60 seconds before making the request, until when I make the request:
I made a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/zVPFmG

This approach would work (we used it but replaced it with an approach that handles error responses instead because it's quite expensive, esp. in a distributed system where we had to store the log in Redis). I'd implement it with an await GetLease() which does the rate limiting followed by an await DoUpdate(). The GetLease() function easily calculate how long it has to wait by looking at the log, which might simplify your fiddle.
